# Bundler install error on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, bundler

Here is the error when gem install bundler:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/dtt# cd /vol/www/emclab/current
root@ubuntu:/vol/www/emclab/current# gem install bundler
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    too many connection resets (http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

The problem is persistent. Any thoughts? thanks.

Comment: Could you put a "--verbose" on the end of that install command?

Comment: solved with: rvmsudo gem install bundler, as a regular user (instead root).

Comment: Should post answer to yourself below and accept it so that it gets removed from the list of unanswered questions. This will save the rest of us time reading already solved questions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the users comment, this can be solved using:

```
rvmsudo gem install bundler
```

*I just had this same issue and was able to solve it using the same method.*